# Making a SQL query using input from user on a form and displaying results on page

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jsp, web-applications

I have a table called Data with rows that contain a number column (all unique), followed by a first name column and last name column.

I'd like to ask the user on a webpage to enter the number and return the first name and last name.

Now what i'm creating is a a webpage using eclipse/tomcat/java/jsp/mysql and Im fairly new to all of this, could anybody point me to some existing examples/resources?

To paint a picture: I'd like have a webpage where it asks the user to enter the unique number, press enter, then it takes the number, performs the query in the backend and reutrns the first name and last names on the webpage.

Comment: Hi Jason, I've seen resources concerning manipulating a table with adds or deletes, but nothing about reads and displaying using webpages and input fields - and currently I'm trying to just have a starting point with any resources that could help me do this

Comment: You can probably use those resources as a starting point, and also look into the "SELECT" SQL keyword.

Comment: I'm more asking for additional resources like websites or recommendations, as I'm not learning much from my current ones. - In terms of my SQL query, I'm pretty confident on it, I'm more interested in learning more how to interact between the sql and the web input field etc.